# How to add a proptypes of either null or number in React.js with prop-types library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I tried:

```
PropTypes.oneOf([
  PropTypes.number,
  null,
]);

PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.number,
  null,
]);
```

None of them work... how can I set a prop to be allowing either null or numbers with prop-types library in React.js?

Comment: `PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.oneOf([null]), PropTypes.number]).isRequired`, have you tried this ?

Comment: @VipulSingh have you? it works?

Comment: I just tried. It doesn't work. I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

well, surprising, prop-types haven't able to support that ... even when someone actually already proposed the change to add `isDefined` into a type..........
Here is the answer https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/90
Its still await to be merged but seems functionality itself is already done. Let's push for its merge if you have the same problem!